# 50 column and 2000000 rows data Convert on datatable to json

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

**I used below this code**
***When I am playing with swagger it is showing error***
**I Get Data On Database using on this code I convert data to DataTable and also convert DataTable to Json Formate**

```
   public IActionResult Get_TblMasterBoard()
   {
            string query = @"select Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4,Name5,Name6,Name7,Name8,Name9,Name10,Name11,Name12,Name13,Name14,Name15,Name16,Name17,Name18,Name19,Name20,Name21,Name22,Name23,Name24,Name25,Name26,Name27,Name28,Name29,Name30,Name31,Name32,Name33,Name34,Name35,Name35,Name36,Name37,Name38,Name39,Name40,Name41,Name42,Name43,Name44,Name45,Name46,Name47,Name48,Name49,Name50 from dbo.FakeTable";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _connection_Helper._getConnectionstring();
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
                {
                    myCon.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                    {
                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader);
                        myReader.Close();
                        myCon.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table));
   }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi @Sharad Kulshrestha, did you set breakpoint and debug your code to check which line makes error? Also what's the error message do you receive?

Comment: Hello @Rena No error on code but I am not able to retrieve data on swagger as it terminates the portal. Because of heavy Data

Comment: Hi @SharadKulshrestha, you mean you have step to the last code return Ok but cannot return the data successfully on swagger, right? What's the error message the swagger displays?

Comment: Hi @Rena Error code: Out of Memory

Comment: You should implement [pagination](https://nordicapis.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-api-pagination/) in your controller to return e.g. a maximum 100 records at a time instead of all records. 2000000 records is just too much data to return in a single request.